How do I remove level 1 attribute using vert.x jsonparser
If I have a complex json, converting it to vert.x JsonObject and then removing the level 1 attribute/array takes a lot of cpu and time. Is there any way it can be achieved using vert.x JsonParser?
Sample Input
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": { "b1": 2},
  "c": [ "3", {"c1": 4}, [9,10]],
  "d": [4, {"d1": 5}, ["5", "6"]],
  "e": {"e1": 7},
  "f": 8
}

Elements to be removed: d, e, f
Output:
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": { "b1": 2},
  "c": [ "3", {"c1": 4}, [9,10]]
}

